# Limit HttpResponseMessage.Content data (ReadAsStringAsync) to specific maximum size

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the following:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(myUrl);
String content = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Is there a way to limit how much is downloaded via the HttpResponseMessage.Content? If I don't trust the URL, and the URL actually feeds back 100 GB, then this could spell trouble... I'd basically like to limit this to a configurable number of bytes - and if there's more, I don't want it! :) Thanks!

Comment: any resolution? I know this is old, but that means that you're most certainly past this problem

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this link will help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.maxresponsecontentbuffersize.aspx

```
HttpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize
```